# Absolutely positioned images in relative container do not move with container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html that is like this

```
<div>
  <div>
    <input class="button"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="father'>
     <img class="img1"></img>
     <img class="img2"></img>
     <img class="img2"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css like this

```
.father {
   position: relative;
}

.img1 {
  position: relative;
}

.img2, .img3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: //some amount
  left: //some amount
}
```

When an error appears under the html, in a div, the img1 gets pushed down, but img2 and img3 remain. Why does this happen? I'd have thought the entire div would be pushed down, and relative to the div, img2 and img3 would move down as well.

After the error appears the DOM looks like

Comment: What exactly does the DOM look like after the error is added?

Comment: Although you have position: relative set on img1, it isn't actually set to any specific position so it will still flow with the content around it.

Comment: Can you please specify where exactly the error is appearing what it consists of?

Comment: An live example of your issue will go a long way. You can post your HTML/JS here and post a link for us to view: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Created a JSfiddle for you [https://jsfiddle.net/zjzr9wv2/](https://jsfiddle.net/zjzr9wv2/)

Comment: As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. You should create a [mcve] of your problem. Emphasis on **complete** (add the error's `HTML` markup and `CSS` as well).

Comment: You have a typo in `class="father"`, does that exist in your live code too? Also, can we see the produced code after the error?

Answer (score 2):

By making img2 and img3 `position: absolute`, they have been removed from the standard flow of the document. They are always going to be positioned relative to their nearest ancestor that has positioning. In this case, that's the `father` div. So whatever you have set for their `top` values will always be how far they are away from the top of the `father` div.

Comment: right, but the father div moves down due to the error appearing, so why aren't the child divs also moving down?

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about the father div moving... I think you need to update the question with better details of what exactly is happening, or better yet, include a live example.